# Can't click on button from Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on any one of the three buttons below but can not find a name, ID or class the identify the

Any hints?

```
<user-tile-actions ng-transclude="actions"> <!----><button ng-if="!vm.user.isBlockingMe         
&amp;&amp; !vm.user.isBlocked" type="button" class="button-height-32 button-padding-10 follow-icon         
button-scs button-scs-shadow" user-follow="vm.user" event-label="user-tile-small"><i class="icon- 
person-plus"></i></button><!----> </user-tile-actions>

<button ng-if="!vm.user.isBlockingMe &amp;&amp; !vm.user.isBlocked" type="button" class="button- 
height-32 button-padding-10 follow-icon button-scs button-scs-shadow" user-follow="vm.user" event- 
label="user-tile-small"><i class="icon-person-plus"></i></button>

<i class="icon-person-plus"></i>
```

I am getting Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: messages:
{"method":"css selector","selector":".button-height-32 button-padding-10 follow-icon button-scs button-scs-shadow"}

[image]

Comment: Try to apply [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@event-label='user-tile-small']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work if it's not in an iframe or anything.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button-scs-shadow").click()
```